# Java или C#, что нужнее сейчас и в перспективе?

Tags: c#, работа, java

Мне 17 лет. Встал выбор. Либо Java (android, кроссплатформа), либо C# (wpf, windows phone). Веб откинул сразу — пробовал , не понравилось. Опыт работы с обеими платформами примерно одинаков (одинаково мал) — пришло как раз время выбирать направление. С# и дотнет импонируют документацией msdn, студией, синтаксическим сахаром шарпа и активным развитием. Java в свою очередь — более «правильной» реализацией платформы (написано под старое — запускается на новом), простотой языка без лишних изысков, оупенсорсностью :) По статистике, на Украине и то, и другое востребовано примерно на одном уровне. Что чаще нужно в мелком городе? Что лучше на перспективу? Кому легче устроится без опыта? Кого чаще берут на удаленку? Во фрилансе что нужнее? Поделитесь своими наблюдениями.
**UPD:**  android + Java и desktop + C#. Думаю, что пойдёт, то и моё.

Comment: На любителя, из этих двух языков - С#. Платят нормально, работы полно, по поводу удаленки не знаю. чем не нравится офис?

Comment: Офис не то, что не нравится. Просто я живу в маленьком городке, где работу программистом днём с огнём не сыщешь. Переезжать не хочу - не люблю суету больших городов.

Comment: @Izobara, ну это правильно в принципе, я  сам не в большом городе работаю

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Я активный сторонник C#, моё мнение предвзято.)

Итак, плюсы .NET:

- Хорошо и быстро развивающийся язык. LINQ и async/await ещё долго будут вне пределов досягаемости других мейнстримовых языков.
- Платформа Windows Phone сейчас растёт, под неё понадобятся приложения, которые уже есть под iOS и Android. Рынок пока не заполнен, можно рискнуть и выиграть.
- WPF — один из немногих вменяемых декстопных GUI-фреймворков. Java в этом плане сильно отстаёт.

Плюсы Java:

- Андроид всё же самая популярная мобильная ось на текущий момент.
- Энтерпрайз пишется в основном на Java.

По поводу кроссплатформенности, она не кажется мне решающим фактором. Обычно проекты пишутся под конкретную платформу, особенно если они завязаны на фронт-энд.

---

Кстати, а где вы нашли отсутствие обратной совместимости в .NET?

Comment: Скомпилируйте код под .net 4.0, и попробуйте запустить под 2.0. Пшык. А написанное под Java 1.4 вполне себе крутится на Java 7

Comment: @Izobara: Вы поняли суть ваших претензий? Код, написанный под _более позднюю_ версию языка не будет работать под _более ранней версией_. Написанное под Java 7 не пойдёт под Java 1.4.

Comment: Также скомпилированное под 2.0 не запустится, как минимум, без перекомпиляции, на 4.0

Comment: Плюсом Java можно назвать бесплатность (не всего конечно), в отличии от .NET.

Comment: @Izobara: почему же? Программа на .NET 4 работает с библиотеками, скомпилированными под .NET 2. [Пруф](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx).

@Anxis: Что? .NET-framework бесплатен, компилятор под него бесплатен, [Visual Studio Express](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) бесплатен. Продвинутая версия Visual Studio, да, стоит денег, но так и IntelliJ Ultimate стоит денег.

Comment: оффтоп

@VladD, `WPF — один из немногих вменяемых декстопных GUI-фреймворков. Java в этом плане сильно отстаёт.`

Что Вы скажете по поводу этой статьи?

http://paulstovell.com/blog/six-years-of-wpf

Опыт с wpf и mvvm у меня совсем небольшой, но даже сейчас некоторые моменты удручают.

Может Вы знаете что-нибудь о планах команды WPF? Планируются ли какие-нибудь нововведения?

Comment: @Veikedo: ну, критика во многом справедлива, в WPF могло бы многое добавиться и упроститься. Тем не менее, в Java UI-фреймворки существенно хуже. Binding, наследуемые стили, ресурсы, вменяемый layout manager (в котором собственные layout-контролы вообще не нужно писать) — всего этого я больше не видел. А какие моменты вам не нравятся в WPF/MVVM? (Хотя это, наверное, тема для отдельного вопроса.) Дышал бы WPF кто-то в спину, они бы и развивались поактивнее. Хотя, с приходом Windows Phone я думаю, им придётся подтянуться.

Comment: @VladD: Вместо IntelliJ IDEA можно использовать Eclipse (при этом теряя только в возможностях рефакторинга), а вот замены Visual Studio нет. Да, есть Visual Studio Express, но там не поддерживаются плагины, а следовательно, не работает Repharper, а это становится уже не удобным.
Если занимаешься веб-разработкой, то надо платить за сервер, а используя JAVA можно использовать Tomcat или Jetty.
Возможно, я преувеличил, говоря, что JAVA абсолютно бесплатна, но согласитесь она обойдётся дешевле.

Answer (score 11):

Учи алгоритмы и ООП. А выбор платформы это уже дело техники и личных предпочтений.
У джавы свои дыры, у шарпа свои. Это практически холивар по данному вопросу.

Comment: Это само собой. Но просто учить теорию скучно. Надо что-то и писать.

Comment: Это понятное дело что надо учить алгоритмы, какой язык программирования спрашивается!

Comment: у меня самого такой же сложный выбор. Но с учётом того, что скоро выйдет в сыет джава 8, стоить обратить внимание на джаву. Ктому же, по слухам и по запросам Джава- программистам БОЛЬШЕ платят денег :)

Comment: Деньги - вторичное)

Comment: опять же. К большому сожалению нельзя за короткие сроки выучить обе платформы. Это как буд-то выбор между ОКНАМИ и ЛИНУКСОМ!..

Comment: и нельзя сразу отсечь одно от другого. В чем то одна ветка лучше, в чем то другая.
Учите джава -- не прогадаете!
Будете работать на шарпе -- не пропадете.
У нас, в Украине, пошла тенденция на шарп. для верности надо статистику пролистывать )

Comment: Я вообще-то с Украины. И тенденцию замечаю)

Comment: вот когда определишся с выбором, прошу огласить всем присутствующим о своем предпочтении... ужос как интересно :)

Comment: Ок. Вроде как решил.

Answer (score 9):

кто сильней слон или кит, честно говоря профессионализм рулит больше чем язык, конечно понятно, что потолок зарплаты может быть разным для программиста работающего на том или ином языке, но добраться до потолка это дело не очень быстрое и обычно к тому времени проблема перехода с одного языка на другой сводится сроку от двух-трех недель до пары месяцев

Comment: С языка на язык - может быть. Но с технологии на технологию - вряд ли. До того времени, как я смогу спокойно прыгать по языкам, надо на чем-то писать.

Answer (score 6):

Молодой человек, вы сначала определитесь с логикой: то вы ищете то что востребованнее то вы ищете, что вам нравится (веб пробовал не понравилось, Java или C# что востребованнее...). Корень лежит там - в этой логике. В вашем возрасте важнее, мне кажется, все таки логика "нравится - не нравится", а не "нужнее - не нужнее". По той простой причине, что то что нравится и получается лучше. В плане денег и шарп и джава примерно одного плана. Джава более международнее что ли разве что, а шарп поместечковее. Как то так.

Из вашего опуса вижу,  кстати, что Java вам нравится поболее dot Net. Так что делайте выводы...

Answer (score 5):

Я - разработчик на C#, но посоветовал бы автору изучать Java.
Desktop-приложения - это умирающее направление разработки, все переходит либо в web, либо на мобильные приложения.

Answer (score 1):

C# для Windows - это как Objective-C для Mac OS. C# активно развивает Microsoft и делает это очень хорошо и что не говори, но приложения написанные на C# будут всегда лучше всех работать на Windows. Это своего рода сфокусированный на Windows язык программирования, как и Objective-C для Mac OS. Просто при выборе C# не надо пытаться разрабатывать кростплатформенные приложения (используя всякие "Mono" и т.п.). И сегодня сделав выбор в сторону C# ни как не проиграешь. Ну а то что сегодняшний программист должен знать хотя бы пару языков, говорить думаю не стоит.

Comment: Ну mono вроде как нормально на линуксе запускает С# программы.

Answer (score -1):

В Java нет структур, в топку её.

> Структуры занимают меньше места в
> памяти, т.к. у них нет заголовка
> описывающий тип данных, указателей на
> таблицы виртуальных методов, а так же
> другие поля, необходимые для
> синхронизации и сборки мусора.
>
> Структуры хранятся в stack’е (но в
> куче, если массив). Выделение памяти в
> stack’е происходит очень быстро: stack
> – заранее выделенный буфер памяти, в
> котором просто резервируется место по
> размеру структуры (в основном, на
> этапе компиляции) путём уменьшения
> значения в stack pointer (уменьшения,
> т.к. данные в stack’е хранятся
> задом-наперёд). Когда функция
> завершает свою работу, то
> «освобождение» всех переменных в
> stack’е происходит один махом путём
> увеличения указателя stack pointer на
> количество байт, необходимых для
> переменных. А выделение и освобождение
> памяти в куче – это огромное
> количество операций, в отличие от
> простого вычитания и суммирования.
>
> Из-за того, что структуры хранятся в
> stack’е, они не требуют сборки мусора.
> Это сильно разгружает сборщик мусора и
> избавляет от проблемы фрагментации
> памяти.
>
> Структуры, поля которых – только value
> types, легко сериализовать в массив
> байт и обратно.

А еще Java-компилятор не оптимизирует хвостовую рекурсию

Comment: ээээ, а о каких структурах идёт речь?

если те что в С\С++ ??? так ни кто не мешает сделать класс с публичными кишками...

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat: Не совсем. Структуры в .NET — это типы данных, передающиеся всегда _по значению_, такие же, как `int`. Массив структур в C#, в отличие от Java, содержит небоксированные объекты — то есть не ссылки на объекты, а сами объекты. Это позволяет например не грузить garbage collector.

Comment: C точки зрения ООП структуры вообще не нужны. Но просто для удобства может быть полезно, если не важно соблюдать ООП

Comment: да, это очень сильно бьет по производительности

Comment: @vkovalchuk88: C#-овские структуры не нарушают инкапсуляции (они не как в C++, у них просто семантика на identity, а value), так что с ООП по идее всё в порядке.

Comment: CoOrds coords1;

        // Initialize:
        coords1.x = 10;
        coords1.y = 20;

        // Display results:
        Console.Write("CoOrds 1: ");
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}", coords1.x, coords1.y);

Пример из мсдна, такие cтруктуры если их много и они сложные это не будет ооп , потому как поменял значение, поламалось все. Но я не говорю что прям нельзя такое делать, просто ООП учебники учат делать по другому.

Comment: господа минусующие, аргуменитурйте хотябы Ваши минусы обоснованно

Comment: подправил ситуацию,  @wefwefgwe это тебе урок на будущее, надо полнее изъяснять свои мысли ибо другие люди не телепаты и могут даже не знать C#...

за подробное описание спасибо! с меня плюс  :)

p.s. хешкод всё больше мне напоминает хабр, "комментарии полезнее поста".