# Java или C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, java

Я девушка, и мне 18. Надо сделать выбор между java, c# и oracle. Так как не имею опыта программирования не на java не на c# не имею понятия что будет лучше для изучения. Также можно выбрать oracle , как управление базами данных. Актуально ли изучение oracle в данный момент? Прошу вашей помощи, так как сама уже запуталась и не знаю с какой точки выбирать то ли что нравится больше или что более актуально.

Comment: СМотря что именно Ты хочешь делать,и почему выбор между C# и Java,почему бы не Python к примеру
Неотговариваю но

Comment: @AigerimK, Подобный вопрос задавался не раз. Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь поиском.

Comment: @AigerimK мне не 18 лет, и я точно не девушка и не женщина, но вопрос меня сильно заинтересовал. Что же это за обстоятельства, заставляющие восемнадцатилетнюю девушку делать такой странный выбор?

Comment: холиваром попахивает... зы а зачем сообщать сколько тебе и лет и пол ?

Comment: @IronVbif Ваш метод универсален или работает только для восемнадцатилетних девушек? Если я пришлю свою фотографию, Вы скажете, какой язык мне следует изучать? А по аватарке на данном сайте?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос на самом то деле далеко не праздный и более того довольно любопытный именно в разрезе:

> Я девушка, и мне 18.

Именно в этом контексте я бы посоветовал выбрать Java. Почему? Потому что он проще и красивее. Шарп он как бы более *мужской* (без обид к любителям Java к коим я и сам отношусь), более сложный, более замороченный что ли...

Как то так.

**Update** 18-летней девочке полагаю в хитросплетении политики MS vs. Sun/Oracle сложно разбираться. Гораздо проще и понятнее ориентироваться в удобстве и красоте. А как известно:

> Хорошо летают только красивые самолеты (с) Туполев А.Н.

Так что Java летает хорошо :)

Comment: Не в сложности дело. Дело скорее в том, что c# это микрософт и все технологии и экосистема только в рамках видения этой компании. Java - это огромное сообщество и огромный багаж открытых проектов и тд тп. Если ближе путь который предлагает Microsoft и соискатель поклонник операционной системы OS Windows то C# и dotNet, если нет то welcome to java и unix-way.

Comment: @huffman, а когда это Java стала частью *nix-way?

Неужели там все переделали  под POSIX?

Comment: @huffman см. апдейт

Answer (score 0):

Будучи новичком, выбирайте тот язык, который вам покажется проще/лучше/удобнее. И все. Никаких холиваров. К тому времени, как для вас станут критичны различия языков, вы уже будете на уровне, на котором такие вопросы будут вызывать улыбку)

Answer (score 0):

Изучать надо не языки, а парадигмы. Выбирать между C# и Java - это всё равно что выбирать между двумя сортами растворимого кофе, вместо того, чтобы попробовать ещё натуральный кофе, чай, сок, шоколадное молоко, да мало ли на свете разных напитков... Главное - не алкоголь!

Для начала советую изучить три языка: любой процедурный (например, C, Pascal, PureBasic), любой конкатенативный (Forth, Factor), любой Лисп (newLisp, CLISP, Scheme). После этого начнёшь понимать, что между ними общего, чем они отличаются. И поймёшь, куда двигаться дальше, и нужен ли тебе вообще ООП (который я считаю таким же тупиком в развитии науки программирования, как флогистон в химии и эфир в физике, но это сугубо моё ИМХО, конечно).

Некоторые парадигмы (например, автоматное программирование) вообще языконезависимы.

Comment: Вместо Forth'а или Factor'а (ни разу про него не слышал) имеет смысл изучать postscript. Принцип тот же, а есть везде.

А лиспоиды считают CLISP и Scheme сильно разными языками, с разными подходами к программированию. Так что их объединять надо с осторожностью

Comment: Factor - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_0QlhYlS8g

Forth - это, скорее, способ мышления. Одна из самых известных книг по Форту таки называется: "Способ мышления - Форт". Язык настолько прост, что 80% фортеров создают свой форт, причём для многих из них этот собственный форт - не игрушка, а реальный инструмент для работы.

Common Lisp и Scheme - это как Ocaml и Haskell. Один больше подходит для реальной жизни, другой более академический, но парадигма та же. Кстати, совсем забыл сказать, что F# какой-нибудь тоже надо изучить, или хотя бы попытаться. Даже неудачная попытка очень много даст.

Answer (score -2):

Незнаю,по моему на C# больше всяких решений,которые упрощают многое

Вот мой ответ 
[Java или C#, что нужнее сейчас и в перспективе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263536/java-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-c-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Comment: Хотя если нет опыта программирования,учи Python

Comment: каких конкретно? Особенно из того, чего нет в Java?

Comment: говорят, если незнаеш куда идти и ничего не умееш - учи пыху

Comment: Дааа пыха тоже ничего